# How to resolve your conflicts while rebasing your code

Tags: git, github

I have to rebase one branch into other branch in git.

But there are 700+ commits and 200+ files. 
While rebasing my code, The conflict occurred in few files at early commits only. And I getting the conflict in few files only.

So is there way so I can rebase my code while I have to resolve all conflicts at once only instead of resolving after each commit.

Comment: I guess he's asking how to resolve his conflicts "once and for all" instead of having to solve them *again* at each phase of the rebase process...

Comment: I have updated my question. Is it under stable now ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Thanks. That is what I am asking.

Comment: In general, no, you can't do this, nor can you control where and when the conflicts would pop up.  I see a big problem here, which is that 700 commits are involved.  Why did you wait so long before merging or rebasing?  Speaking of merging, if you want to resolve all the conflicts in one place, then merging is the way to go.

Comment: "But there are 700+ commits and 200+ files." When you are in such a case, I think you much better should merge instead of rebase to have less conflicts (and better perf)...

Comment: Good things there was very less conflicts files. I used Webstrom and did it. I only use use rebase. Thanks you guys for you reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be looking in to `git rerere`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

I've never used it myself, so can't offer any examples, but the description at the link above states:

> This command assists the developer [resolve the same conflicts over and over again] by recording conflicted automerge results and corresponding hand resolve results on the initial manual merge, and applying previously recorded hand resolutions to their corresponding automerge results.

This basically allows you to **Re**use **Re**corded **Re**solution (hence `rerere`)

You simply run `git rerere` when the first auto-merge conflict is hit, then run it again once you've resolved it. Git will then apply the same resolution to your repo every time it spots the same conflict.

Comment: I'm note sure it will have the same conflicts every time so it seems that `rerere` will be of no help here.