# Git rebase a long running feature branch on top of develop

Tags: git

We have a long running `feature` branch created from `develop`. A few people have been working on `feature`(work on sub branches created from `feature` and merge back to it) for a month, but never sync `feature` with `develop`.

I'm trying do `git rebase develop` on `feature` today, there are too many conflicts, it seems for each new commit git rebase creates, there are always conflicts, however many of them are not a problem if only comparing the first and last commit.

What's the best way to sync `feature` with `develop` in this case?
For a long running feature branch like this, what's the best way to keep them in sync? (If I do `git rebase develop` very often and keep resolving conflicts, is it good ?)

Comment: Why are you rebasing? The standard way to do this would be to [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: I've basically seen [this exact same question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641860/how-to-resolve-your-conflicts-while-rebasing-your-code) already. I'm not clear why everyone has decided why rebasing all the time is a good idea. rebasing is designed for simple merges to keep your branch clean. Not for complex merges. You can also look into [`git merge --squash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just merge develop into feature? It's a long-running branch, so rebasing does not seem like the right solution.

`git merge develop`

You will still have to resolve the conflicts, but that can't be helped with long-running branches. Periodic merging seems to reflect your branch setup better than trying to rebase it, which re-writes the commit history.